# How to add color to alternate dynamic created rows

Tags: visualforce, css, style

I have this below code where I create dynamic rows on button click.

I want to add different color to all odd and even rows. How can I do that?

```
<style>
        .redColor{
            background-color : red;
        }
        .blueColor{
             background-color : blue;
        }


    </style>


    <apex:variable var="i" value="{!0}"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!wrappers}" var="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
        <apex:variable var="i" value="{!i+1}"/>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="{!IF(MOD(i,2)==0,'redColor','blueColor')}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.acc.Start_Date__c}" html-placeholder="Start Date &#42;" 
                    style="color: #16325c;border: 1px solid #d8dde6;border-radius: 0.25rem;transition: border 0.1s linear, background-color 0.1s linear;">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!wrapper.startdateErrorMessage }" style="color:red"/>
               </apex:inputField>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.acc.Product__c}" onchange="validateSite();" styleClass="child_fields"
                html-placeholder="Site &#42;" id="siteID"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.acc.Product__c}" onchange="validateProduct();" id="pNameID" styleClass="child_fields" html-placeholder="Product &#42;"/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [just a CSS question](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html).

```
<style>
    .row:nth-child(even) { background-color: #CCC; }
    .row:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #FFF; }
</style>
```

Comment: Its not working...

Comment: You probably just need more [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: i tried using the above code which i have updated now..still that also not working

Comment: Have you tried `inspect element`? The styles should definitely be applied, they may just get overridden by something more specific. The most specific style wins.